# Java maven dependency vulnerability warning

Tags: java, selenium, maven

When I am trying to set dependencies (Selenium, Webdrivermanager) on a maven project it gives me an error like ->

[Dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ1Q2.png)

[Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI9Ml.png)

Some other versions don't have this issue but I need to use this version. Also, my team uses the same version and they don't have any issues like that.

I set my env. variables MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not an error but a warning. If you use that version, you will be pulling transitive dependencies on 3 other artifacts that have been found to contain some vulnerabilities. If you don't care about it, you can just go on. If you do, there's not much you can do except hoping that the provider of the artifact you're using will upgrade their dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my team uses the same version and they don't have any issues like that.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: It's just that your colleagues don't have vulnerability warnings enabled on their IDE. Either you turn it off too, or you all approach the problem by removing the vulnerabilities (and that may be long and sometimes out of your control, even though it's the right thing to do)